# hosting a local dynamic wordpress website

Tags: html, css, mysql, wordpress, hosting

i am having a problem of exporting my local "wordpress" website and it's giving my an xml file but with all in one wp migration it's giving me a "WPRESS" file. i can't pay for the business subscription just to install a few plugins that'll make my website live because it's expensive. is there a way to convert these files to dynamic files and host it?

Comment: Welcome! Please read the documentation about what a good SO question needs: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First you need ZIP all wordpress files and also export your SQL file. Then upload that zip file to your Hosting C-panel and extract it also import SQL file to your server and copy that server name and password and pest it into your config file.
for detailed instruction you can follow below blog
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/